# Uniqueness of line through a point, perpendicular with an affine space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the affine space $D=q+D_0$, with $p\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash D$ and $L$ the perpendicular line through $p$ on $D$. This line $L$ is unique, i.e. $L$ is the unique line through $p$, perpendicular with $D$, such that $L \cap D\ne \emptyset $.

Proof: Consider an arbitrary line $M$ through $p$, perpendicular with $D$, with $M \cap D \ne \emptyset$. Assume $M \cap D = \{z\}$. Then $\underline{M \subseteq p+D_0^\perp}$, and therefore $\underline{z \in (p+D_0^\perp)\cap D}$. But then we have $\underline{D=z+D_0} $ and $\underline{p+D_0^\perp=z+D_0^\perp}$, which imply: $(p+D_0^\perp)\cap D=(z+D_0^\perp)\cap(z+D_0) = z+(D_0^\perp\cap D_0) = \{z\}.$

We can conclude that $z$ is independent of the choice of $M$, and therefore $M$ is the unique line through $p$ and $z$.

This is the only proof in my book that I don't understand completely. I'm taking an exam tomorrow, so I would be infinitely grateful if someone could explain to me where the underlined parts come from.

Answer (score 1):

The first underline simply expresses that $M$ is perpendicular to $D$, from which the second underline follows immediately ($A\subseteq B \land a\in A\implies a\in B$). But then, since $a\in A\cap B\implies a\in A\land a\in B$, you also have that $z\in p+D_0^\perp$, so just as with $D=z+D_0$, this affine space can also be expressed as $z+D_0^\perp$.